# Last player folds on the river

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

In an online Texas Hold'em game, two players are still active when the river card is dealt. The first player folds after seeing the river card. The remaining player folds and a message appear on the screen that says game over. It does not indicate how much was in the pot or who won the pot. What happened to the existing pot?

Answer (score 2):

The last player won the pot. The last player won as soon as the other player folded. It likely went quick and the pot amount was reset as soon as the hand was done and you simply missed it.